# How to pass the address of a thread function as a callback to winapi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, pointers

I have a simple thread and inside the execute I try to call EnumWindows() with the address of one of the functions defined in the thread.
So I'm trying to do this: EnumWindows(@cbEnumWindowsClickOK, 0); where cbEnumWindowsClickOK is an EnumWindowProc defined inside the thread class, like so:

```
TAutoClickOKThread = class(TThread)
private
     fExitEvent : THandle;
     function cbEnumWindowsClickOK(Wnd: HWND; Info: Pointer): BOOL;
public
   constructor Create(ExitEvent : Thandle);
   procedure Execute(); override;
end;
```

When I try this I keep getting "Error: Variable required", hinting that it doesn't interpret @cbEnumWindowsClickOK as an address. If I move the function to a global scope (removing it from the thread) it does work.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Comment: +1: Please consider this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9263584/744588). Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass `EnumWindows` a plain old function, i.e. one that is not bound to an instance. You must pass the instance in separately. Like this:

```
function EnumFunc(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  Result := TAutoClickOKThread(lParam).cbEnumWindowsClickOK(hwnd);
  //note that there is now no need for the Info parameter
end;
...
procedure TAutoClickOKThread.Execute;
begin
  ...
  EnumWindows(EnumFunc, LPARAM(Self));
  ...
end;
```

The reason it must be done this way is that an instance method does not match the required signature for `EnumWindows`. An instance method has an extra, implicit, parameter containing the instance reference, i.e. `Self`. This is how you are able to refer to instance members. But the signature for `EnumFunc` does not cater for this.

Comment: You can use a class method if it is declared as `static', but you still need to use the callback's `lParam` parameter to pass the `Self` pointer around.

Comment: @Remy whilst that works too I'm not sure that it's any better. Especially if the class is declared in the interface section then this approach results in extra clutter in my view.

Comment: @David I find it kind of weird that you can't pass the address of the method from the class. As far as I know for each class there is just one instance of a function and all the class instances use the same one, so it seems logical there will be away to get that function address...

Comment: @Ran An instance function has the wrong signature. That's the problem. An instance function has an extra implicit parameter, namely the instance.

Comment: @David: in Delphi, using static class methods isn't as useful other than for code organization, since everything in a unit have implicit friendship with each other. In C/C++, where implicit friendship does not exist, using static class methods as callbacks is more useful.

Comment: @Ran: when David refers to "the instance", he's referring to the `Self` pointer.

Comment: @Ran, **methods** have implicit first parameter - `Self`, therefore signatures fails to match. You can look at `MakeObjectInstance` for different approach to this problem.

Comment: But you can't actually use MakeObjectInstance since that is just for window procs.