# How to pass a method as callback to a Windows API call (Follow-up)?

Tags: delphi, winapi, callback, thunk

This post is a follow-up of a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706637/how-to-pass-the-address-of-a-thread-function-as-a-callback-to-winapi) posted here by [Ran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918399/ran).

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7706674/744588) sticks to the use of the usual a plain old function.

This excerpt particularly catch my attention:

> An instance method has an extra, implicit, parameter containing the
>   instance reference, i.e. Self.

With the firm conviction that there should be a way to use a kind of "parameters" adapter (to rephrase get rid of the uneeded Self implicit reference and provide a pointer to a complying adapted callback function), I end up finding this [article](http://www.howtodothings.com/computers/a1411-callback-a-class.html) entitled **Callback a class** by [Peter Morris](http://www.howtodothings.com/p2974-peter-morris.html).

To sum up, he uses thunking technique as adaptation trick. (Disclaimer: I never tested the code).

I know it's not very clean as a solution but it allows OO design with all the supposed benefits.

**My Question:**

Knowing that *TCallbackThunk* is based on the callback function signature, what would be the answer of the above refered post if doing it as Peter Morris did is the way to go?

.

Comment: I'd add what some API callbacks are allowing a workaround with lParam, but some are not (eg: WinNLS on the illustration). Also, this should be called StdcallThunk or something.

Comment: This won't work because the code that is produced will not reside in an executable page. You can fix that problem. But then you will have code that can only work on x86 and fails on x64.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thank you. My box is a x86 and any code working in Delphi 5, 7, 2007, XE will do. I must edit the post.

Comment: You will need to use VirtualAlloc to allocate an executable page. Don't do anything daft and make your stack executable! But really, I can't understand why such an approach would be better than a standard function.

Comment: what will cause an illustrated code to fail is DEP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to go through all that work since `EnumWindows` (the function in the referenced question) provides a data parameter. You can put whatever value you want there, such as the object reference demonstrated in the answer. Morris's technique is better suited for callback functions that don't provide any general-purpose data parameter.

To adapt the answer to use Morris's code, you'll first need to make sure the signature of the callback method matches the signature of the API's callback function. Since we're calling `EnumWindows`, we need a two-argument function returning Bool. The calling convention needs to be stdcall (because Morris's code assumes it, and it's difficult to thunk any other calling convention).

```
function TAutoClickOKThread.cbEnumWindowsClickOK(
  Wnd: HWnd; Param: LParam): Bool; stdcall;
begin
  // ...
end;
```

Next, we set up the `TCallbackThunk` data structure with all the machine code and the jump offset referring to the intended callback method.

However, we don't use the way Morris described. His code puts the data structure on the stack. That means we're putting *executable code* on the *stack*. Modern processors and operating systems don't allow that anymore — the OS will halt your program. We could get around that by calling `VirtualProtect` to modify the permissions of the current stack page, allowing it to be executed, but that makes the whole page executable, and we don't want to leave the program open for attack. Instead, we'll allocate a block of memory especially for the thunk record, separate from the stack.

```
procedure TAutoClickOKThread.Execute;
var
  Callback: PCallbackThunk;
begin
  Callback := VirtualAlloc(nil, SizeOf(Callback^),
    Mem_Commit, Page_Execute_ReadWrite);
  try
    Callback.POPEDX := $5A;
    Callback.MOVEAX := $B8;
    Callback.SelfPtr := Self;
    Callback.PUSHEAX := $50;
    Callback.PUSHEDX := $52;
    Callback.JMP := $E9;
    Callback.JmpOffset := Integer(@TAutoClickOKThread.cbEnumWindowsClickOK)
      - Integer(@Callback.JMP) - 5;

    EnumWindows(Callback, 0);
  finally
    VirtualFree(Callback);
  end;
end;
```

Note that those are 32-bit x86 instructions in that record. I have no idea what the corresponding x86_64 instructions would be.

Comment: +1: Very instructive! Before I accept the answer I just want to ascertain 2 things given that Morris's code is aging. 1) Is the pointer adjustement still valid (VMT/TObject changes between version) 2) Same with the hardcoded ASM instruction. I must confess I know little of ASM and BASM. Thank you.

Comment: I can see clearly now why doing code injection might compromise security.

Comment: The pointer adjustment is to compensate for the size of a JMP instruction. The offset in a JMP instruction is relative to the *next* instruction (because EIP is advanced before address calculations occur). It has nothing to do with VMT sizes or objects. X86 instructions haven't changed.