# Bringing TCallbackThunk to 64-bit via anonymous function

Tags: delphi, winapi, assembly, 32bit-64bit, anonymous-function

I have an issue porting some code to 64-bit. It's purpose is to declare a method-like function as callback for WinAPI. Some may know this as `TCallbackThunk` (see [this SO answer for some further explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9263584/4236400)).

I think this code is older, but uses the same approach. It should work with `TCallbackThunk` as well.
Let me show you the code as it works for 32-bit:

```
unit SubClassing;

interface

uses
  Windows;

type
  TCallbackMode = (cbNoCallSuper, cbKeepResult, cbUseSuperResult);

  TWndProc = procedure(Window: HWND; var Message: LongInt;
    var WParam: Longint; var LParam: Longint;
    var LResult: LongInt; var Mode: TCallbackMode) of object;

type
  PSubClassInfo = ^TSubClassInfo;
  TSubClassInfo = record
    OriginalWndProc: Pointer;
    NewWndProc: TWndProc;
    Handle: HWnd;
    Stub: Pointer;
  end;

function SubClassWindow(Handle: HWnd; WndProc: TWndProc): PSubClassInfo;
procedure UnSubClassWindow(var Info: PSubClassInfo);

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

function MakeProcInstance(Data: Pointer; Code: Pointer): Pointer;
begin
{$IFDEF WIN64}
  Assert(False); // lacks implementation for 64-bit
{$ELSE}
  // A simple GetMem will _not_ do the trick.
  // To avoid conflicting with DEP it is essential that the page will
  // be marked as being executable.
  Result := VirtualAlloc(nil, 15, $3000, $40);
  asm
    MOV BYTE PTR [EAX], $B9
    MOV ECX, Data
    MOV DWORD PTR [EAX+$1], ECX
    MOV BYTE PTR [EAX+$5], $5A
    MOV BYTE PTR [EAX+$6], $51
    MOV BYTE PTR [EAX+$7], $52
    MOV BYTE PTR [EAX+$8], $B9
    MOV ECX, Code
    MOV DWORD PTR [EAX+$9], ECX
    MOV BYTE PTR [EAX+$D], $FF
    MOV BYTE PTR [EAX+$E], $E1
  end;
{$ENDIF}
end;

procedure FreeProcInstance(ProcInstance: Pointer);
begin
  VirtualFree(ProcInstance, 15, $8000);
end;

function MultiCaster(SubClassInfo: PSubClassInfo; Window: HWND; Message,
  WParam: Longint; LParam: Longint): LongInt; stdcall;
var
  Mode: TCallbackMode;
  Res: LongInt;
begin
  SubClassInfo.NewWndProc(Window, Message, WParam, LParam, Result, Mode);

  if Mode <> cbNoCallSuper then
  begin
    Res := CallWindowProc(SubClassInfo^.OriginalWndProc, Window, Message, wParam, lParam);
    if Mode = cbUseSuperResult then
      Result := Res;
  end;
end;

function SubClassWindow(Handle: HWnd; WndProc: TWndProc): PSubClassInfo;
begin
  Result := new(PSubClassInfo);

  ZeroMemory(Result, SizeOf(TSubClassInfo));
  Result^.NewWndProc := WndProc;
  Result^.Handle := Handle;
  Result^.Stub := MakeProcInstance(Result, @MultiCaster);
  Result^.OriginalWndProc := Pointer(SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, Integer(Result^.Stub)));
end;

procedure UnSubClassWindow(var Info: PSubClassInfo);
begin
  if Assigned(Info) then
  begin
    if Assigned(Info^.OriginalWndProc) then
    begin
      SetWindowLong(Info^.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, Integer(Info^.OriginalWndProc));
      FreeProcInstance(Info^.Stub);
    end;

    Dispose(Info);
  end;
  Info := nil;
end;

end.
```

Before porting the assembly code of `MakeProcInstance` to 64-bit, I wanted to try on a solution with anonymous function first. This would provide better maintainability as the assembly code becomes obsolete. Therefore, I declared

```
TMultiCasterFunc = reference to function(Window: HWND; Message,
  WParam: Longint; LParam: Longint): LongInt stdcall;
```

and redeclared `TSubClassInfo` as

```
TSubClassInfo = record
  OriginalWndProc: Pointer;
  NewWndProc: TWndProc;
  Handle: HWnd;
  Stub: TMultiCasterFunc;
end;
```

Then, I implemented a function

```
function GetMultiCasterFunction(const ASubClassInfo: PSubClassInfo): TMultiCasterFunc;
begin
  Result := function(Window: HWND; Message, WParam: Longint; LParam: Longint): LongInt stdcall
            begin
              Result := MultiCaster(ASubClassInfo, Window, Message, WParam, LParam);
            end;
end;
```

Functions `SubClassWindow` and `UnSubClassWindow` were edited to this:

```
function SubClassWindow(Handle: HWnd; WndProc: TWndProc): PSubClassInfo;
begin
  Result := new(PSubClassInfo);

  ZeroMemory(Result, SizeOf(TSubClassInfo));
  Result^.NewWndProc := WndProc;
  Result^.Handle := Handle;
  Result^.Stub := GetMultiCasterFunction(Result);
  Result^.OriginalWndProc := Pointer(SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, NativeInt(@(Result^.Stub))));
end;

procedure UnSubClassWindow(var Info: PSubClassInfo);
begin
  if Assigned(Info) then
  begin
    if Assigned(Info^.OriginalWndProc) then
    begin
      SetWindowLong(Info^.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, Integer(Info^.OriginalWndProc));
      FreeProcInstance(@(Info^.Stub));
    end;

    Dispose(Info);
  end;
  Info := nil;
end;
```

I was very happy to see that the code really compiles. I wasn't expecting this.
Unfortunately, I get various exceptions when the code is being executed. For instance, I get an `AV at address 0000000000419A32 reading address FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` in `System._IntfCopy` when calling `GetMultiCasterFunction`.

Is there anything wrong on how I use anonymous function? FYI, I am doing this with Delphi XE4. What should I try?

I have some experience in ASM. So I would be able to do a separate solution for 64-bit. But that should be the last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything wrong on how I use anonymous function?

Yes there is. When you use `SetWindowLong` passing `GWL_WNDPROC` you need to supply a window procedure. That is a function pointer of the following type:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
  _In_ HWND   hwnd,
  _In_ UINT   uMsg,
  _In_ WPARAM wParam,
  _In_ LPARAM lParam
);
```

I took this from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573.aspx).

In Delphi syntax this would be:

```
function WindowProc(
  hwnd: HWND;
  uMsg: UINT;
  wParam: WPARAM;
  lParam: LPARAM
): LRESULT; stdcall;
```

For a start, note the types used. Very different from yours. In a 64 bit build, `WPARAM`, `LPARAM` and `LRESULT` are all 64 bit types. You should fix that.

The big issue though is that this not compatible with an anonymous method. An anonymous method in Delphi is implemented as an interface. A Win32 window procedure is categorically not an interface.

So if you wish to continue in this vein you will need to stick with the `VirtualAlloc` and assembler type thunking approach. If you want to use an anonymous method then you'll need to use different asm that is capable of invoking the interface method.

To learn how to adapt your asm that calls a method into code that invokes an anonymous method I suggest you read the following:

- http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/01/using-anonymous-methods-in-method.html
- http://delphisorcery.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/anonymous-method-overloading.html
- https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/anonimous-methods-in-delphi-the-internals/

If you are prepared to use `of object` methods then the Delphi VCL code will show you how to do it. This technique is exemplified in the window procedure handling for `TWinControl`. Naturally when Embarcadero introduced the 64 bit Windows compiler, and the 64 bit VCL, they had to update their thunking code to support 64 bit.

Comment: The thunking code used for VCL `WndProc` methods, for both 32bit and 64bit, is handled by the  `MakeObjectInstance()` function in the `System.Classes` unit.